# Two buttons, two instances of control class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

**ECMAScript 6**

So far there are two buttons on the page: edit and delete. There will be more (add comment etc.). So, I would like to develop some general approach and not just operate on each button individually.

Each button is of class "custom-control" and should send an AJAX request.

Into the button tag I have included the information necessary for the request (url etc.):

```
<button id="main-object-delete" data-url="{{  object.get_delete_url }}" data-redirect="{{  object.get_delete_success_url }}" type="button" class="custom-main custom-control custom-delete btn btn-default " aria-label="Left Align">
```

The code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    class GeneralManager {

        // Creates managers for each type of controls.

        constructor() {
            this.handle_buttons();

        } // constructor

        handle_buttons(){
            let $button_list = $('.custom-control')

            $button_list.each(function(index, button){
                let button_manager =  new ControlManager(button);
            });
        }

    } // GeneralManager


    function show_get_form(data,  button, url, redirect){
        let nest = button.closest(".custom-nest")
        nest.innerHTML = data;
        let act_cancel_manager = new SubmitCancelManager(url, redirect);
    }

    class ControlManager {
        // Operates on main object only.


        ajax_get(){         
            $.ajax({method: "GET",
                    url: self.url,              
                    success: function(data){ show_get_form(data, 
                                             self.button, 
                                             self.url,
                                             self.redirect); },
                    error: generalFail
                    });     
        } // ajax_get

        constructor(button){            
            self = this; // Protection against binding "this" to something else.
            this.button = button;
            this.url = this.button.getAttribute("data-url")         
            this.redirect = this.button.getAttribute("data-redirect")
            this.button.onclick = this.ajax_get;
        } // constructor        

    }

    let general_manager = new GeneralManager(); 
}); // $( document ).ready(function()
```

The idea was that for each button a new ControlManager object is created.

The problem is that both buttons trigger the request to the url for deletion. Delete button was the last of the two. If I change the order of the buttons, both buttons will send the request to the edit url.

Could you help me understand why my idea of assigning a separate instance of the ControlManager class to different buttons doesn't work. And how to cope with this problem most elegantly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
constructor(button){            
        self = this;
```

This creates a (=one) variable named `self`. So the second instance overwrites the value set by the first one.

```
ajax_get(){         
  $.ajax({method: "GET",
          url: self.url,
```

Here you refer to the global variable `self`.

Forget `self` and use arrow functions where necessary:

```
ajax_get(){         
    $.ajax({method: "GET",
            url: this.url,              
            success: data => show_get_form(data, 
                                     this.button, 
                                     this.url,
                                     this.redirect),
```